# File not found when calling bash from Java

Tags: java, bash

I'm having the next error when execute a cmd command using Java. I'm working in a mac laptop. This is my code:

```
private static String exportContainerFromImage(String container) {
    //docker export mysql_dummy > ~/Documents/mysql_dummy.tar
    String errorMessage = "";
    String[] cmdArgs =
        {"docker export mysql_dummy > ~/Documents/mysql_dummy.tar", "bash"};
     Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArgs);
  }
```

But I'm getting the error, error=2, No such file or directory, if I execute the command directly on the terminal it runs successfully, I tried also changing the directory to ~\\Documents\\mysql_dummy.tar and got the same result.

But if I run the command with the arguments:

```
{"docker create -ti --name mysql_dummy mysql", "bash"};
```

It runs properly

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess : java doesn't understand the `~`. Either that or you are not running the program as your user

Comment: What happens if you use and absolute path ? i.e. `"docker export mysql_dummy > /home/rasilvap/Documents/mysql_dummy.tar"` ?

Comment: the is trying to launch an executable called `docker export mysql_dummy > ~/Documents/mysql_dummy.tar` which sure does not exist. If using an array, Runtime does not split it and (tries to) start the executable named in first element of the array - additionally it is the shell that interprets `>`, so it will not work unless executing one

Comment: @Aserre I got the same error with "/home/rasilvap/Documents/mysql_dummy.tar"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're conflating 'shell magic' with 'an OS'. Also, you seem to be wildly confused about what the array form of cmdArgs does, because you've tagged a bash in there at the end. That array is supposed to contain the executable's full path at `arr[0]`, and all arguments at `arr[1]` and up. `docker create -ti ...` is clearly not a filename, and `bash` is clearly not an argument.

### Shell magic?

If you type:

`docker create -ti --name mysql_dummy mysql`

on the command line, bash (or cmd.exe if on windows, or whatever shell you are using) reads it and does a whole bunch of replacement magic and parsing on this. It's **the shell** that does this, not the OS, and java's processbuilder stuff is not a shell and therefore isn't going to do all that. What you're attempting to do? Run that entire line as if it's a single file name that is executable which it clearly isn't.

This is all shell magic - all things that you CANNOT do with exec. Fortunately, java is a programming language, so you can do all these things by, well, programming it.

- Parsing out params by splitting on whitespace.
- quoting to avoid that splitting, but then removing the quotes.
- Treating `~` as a ref to a homedir.
- Replacing `*` and `?` in filename paths.
- Variable substitution
- Setting up redirects with `> somefile.txt` or `2> /dev/null` or `< file.in` or whatnot.

**You** must do those things.

In addition, `exec` cannot be used to this, period. As usual, the only non-problematic way to run processes is to **always use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), no exceptions**. Consider `runtime.exec` a known-broken method you must never call.

ProcessBuilder lets you redirect the output.

```
String[] cmdArgs = {
  "/bin/docker" // note, FULL PATH!
  "export",
  "mysql_dummy"
};

File out = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents/mysql_dummy.tar");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArgs);
pb.redirectOutput(new File(out));
pb.start();
```

That does what you want, presumably.

The alternative is to make a script (script.sh or script.bat) and then start bash or cmd.exe and ask it to run that script.

`String[] args = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "/fully/qualified/path/to/the/script.sh" }`

and then exec that. Now you can pile `*.txt`, `> foobar.txt`, `~/homediref`, and all the other shellisms in that script as much as you like.

Comment: .. and on windows I believe `*.txt` probably works, but not on posix OSes, and PATH searching sometimes also works. But given that it's all 'sometimes' and 'OS dependent', best not to go anywhere near this.

Comment: `"/bin/bash", "-c", "/fully/qualified/path/to/the/script.sh"` is a silly invocation.   Either `/fully/qualified/path/to/the/script.sh` is executable in which case it would have a shebang line already specify shell to invoke, or would be guessed, or it is not executable in which case the command will fail with "/fully.../script.sh: permission denied".

Answer (score 0):

Overall @rzwiterloot's answer is good, but there are some alternatives it leaves out.

First, what I would consider the best solution to this problem: the `-o` [option to `docker export`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/#options).

```
"docker", "export", "mysql_dummy", "-o", "Documents/mysql_dummy.tar"
```

Ignoring `~/` here, this set of command and arguments will achieve the same thing as `... > Documents/mysql_dummy.tar` but doesn't rely on the shell for the redirection; `docker export` is perfectly capable of handling that operation itself.

Second, if you wanted to run a shell command from the program, you could.  I would not recommend this.  But in certain circumstances it might make sense.

> The alternative is to make a script

You don't have to put the command in a separate file.  Actually this is one inaccuracy in @rzwiterloot's answer; `-c` allows you to pass *command(s)* to `bash`, not the path to a file containing commands.

```
"bash", "-c", "docker export mysql_dummy > ~/Documents/mysql_dummy.tar"
```

However, I'd recommend you avoid invoking shells from any program you write.  They're quirky and esoteric and there's almost always a simpler way to achieve what you want, such as `docker export`'s `-o` optiopn, in this case.